# Access JavaScript variable in .js file?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a normal html site, it defines a variable called *myVar*. This is the declaration:

```
var myVar = something_that_is_set_dynamically;
```

Now I have a js file and I need to get the value of myVar in that file. How would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have added the javascript file after you have declared your `myVar`.

For instance:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = "foobar";
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="yourJsFileUses-myVar.js"></script>

    <!-- you cannot declare myVar here, because "yourJsFile.js" is already
         being executed, so you have to declare your myVar before you include
         your javascript file -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script:

```
do_something_with(myVar);
```

And make sure the `<script>` that uses it appears after the `<script>` that defines it, or doesn't use it outside of a function that isn't run under the defining `<script>` has been processed.

The only impact that putting something in a different file (or inline script element) has, is that it won't be available under the browser has parsed it. The first script will run before hoisting has been applied to the second script.

Answer (score 1):

Include the file in your HTML page's header:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="yourfile.js"></script>
```

If the variable is global (i.e., it is not declared inside a function) it will be visible to your whole page.